# Distribution of the sample mean of Poisson random variables

Tags: distributions, mean, poisson-distribution, sample, sum

Suppose that you have data x which is modeled as a realization of a Poisson random variable X with expected value $\lambda$>0. I know that the sum of Poisson random variables is also Poisson distributed, but is this also the case for the sample mean ($\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$)?

Comment: Another point is that a Possion random variable has variance equal to the expected value but the sample mean has its variance $\frac1n$ times its expected value

Comment: Further details can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085072/sampling-distribution-of-sample-mean-for-poisson-distribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the sample mean of an independent sample from a Poisson distribution is **NOT** Poisson distributed. It is clear from the fact that a Poisson random variable can only have integer values, but the mean of such a sample does not need to be an integer.

But, the sum of the sample ($n$ times the mean) do have a Poisson distribution, and all wanted probabilities can be calculated from that.